# Using destructuring assignment results to not defined

Tags: reactjs, eslint

ES-lint wants me to use destructuring state assignment in `{this.state.dropDownValue}`. But if I do that, the `dropDownValue` gets undefined. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

```
const dropDownList = [
  <FormattedMessage id="bottomPanel.adherenceScores" />,
  <FormattedMessage id="bottomPanel.adherenceJourney" />,
  <FormattedMessage id="bottomPanel.adherenceTrends" />,
];

class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    dropDownValue: dropDownList[0]
  };

  dropDownUpdate = e => this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });

  render() {
    return() {
      <div>
        <UncontrolledDropdown>
          <DropdownToggle tag="div" className="test">
            <div className="bottompanel-dropdown">{this.state.dropDownValue}</div>
          </DropdownToggle>          
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
      </div>
    }
  }
```

Comment: where is `dropDownList` declared?

Comment: Feel free to edit your question so future users can have a complete context.

Comment: If I am not wrong, isn't the state initialised in the `constructor`?

Comment: thanks @larz, i have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.state` is `{ dropDownValue: 'something' }` then you should be able to destructure it using `const { dropDownValue } = this.state;` inside your `render` function.

```
render() {
  const { dropDownValue } = this.state;
  return() {
    <div>
      <UncontrolledDropdown>
        <DropdownToggle tag="div" className="test">
          <div className="bottompanel-dropdown">{dropDownValue}</div>
        </DropdownToggle>          
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks!
so you actually need to declare it again inside the render function
i thought it can access beyond the render function